# Swift: Should ViewModel be a struct or class?

Tags: swift, mvvm, struct, closures

I am trying to use MVVM pattern in my new project. First time, I created all my view model to struct. But when I implemented async business logic such as fetchDataFromNetwork with closures, closures capture old view model value then updated to that. Not a new view model value.

Here is a test code in playground.

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

struct ViewModel {
  var data: Int = 0

  mutating func fetchData(completion:()->()) {
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!) {
      result in
      self.data = 10
      print("viewModel.data in fetchResponse : \(self.data)")
      completion()
      XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
      }.resume()
  }
}

class ViewController {
  var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel() {
    didSet {
      print("viewModel.data in didSet : \(viewModel.data)")
    }
  }

  func changeViewModelStruct() {
    print("viewModel.data before fetch : \(viewModel.data)")

    viewModel.fetchData {
      print("viewModel.data after fetch : \(self.viewModel.data)")
    }
  }
}

var c = ViewController()
c.changeViewModelStruct()
```

Console prints

```
viewModel.data before fetch : 0
viewModel.data in didSet : 0
viewModel.data in fetchResponse : 10
viewModel.data after fetch : 0
```

The problem is View Model in ViewController does not have new Value 10.

If I changed ViewModel to class, didSet not called but View Model in ViewController has new Value 10.

Answer (score 16):

You should use a class.

If you use a struct with a mutating function, the function should not perform the mutation within a closure; you should **not** do the following:

```
struct ViewModel {
  var data: Int = 0

  mutating func myFunc() {
      funcWithClosure() {
          self.data = 1
      }
  }
}
```

> If I changed ViewModel to class, didSet not called

Nothing wrong here - that's the expected behavior.

---

If you prefer to use `struct`, you can do

```
  func fetchData(completion: ViewModel ->()) {
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!) {
      result in
      var newViewModel = self
      newViewModel.data = 10
      print("viewModel.data in fetchResponse : \(self.data)")
      completion(newViewModel)
      XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
      }.resume()
  }


  viewModel.fetchData { newViewModel in
     self.viewModal = newViewModel
      print("viewModel.data after fetch : \(self.viewModel.data)")
    }
```

---

Also note that the closure provided to `dataTaskWithURL` does not run on the main thread. You might want to call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {...}` in it.

Comment: So there is no way to use struct with async API call @Code? Because I prefer use struct than class.

Comment: @Paul Edited my post (again).

Comment: Yeah, that is a bad design. :( I should use class for in this case. Thanks @Code.

Comment: Despite the fact that it has a bad design, with using class, writing unit tests are a lot easier. (Mocking methods for struct is really a frustrating task)

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `self.data` in two options: either use a return parameter in your closure for `fetchResponse`( using `viewModel` as `struct`) OR you can create your own set-method/closure and use it in your `init` method(using `viewModel` as `class`).

```
class ViewModel {
var data: Int = 0
func fetchData(completion:()->()) {
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!) {
        result in
        self.data = 10
        print("viewModel.data in fetchResponse : \(self.data)")
        completion()
        XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
        }.resume()
    }
}

class ViewController {
    var viewModel: ViewModel! { didSet { print("viewModel.data in didSet : \(viewModel.data)") } }

    init( viewModel: ViewModel ) {
        // closure invokes didSet
        ({ self.viewModel = viewModel })()
    }

    func changeViewModelStruct() {
        print("viewModel.data before fetch : \(viewModel.data)")

        viewModel.fetchData {
            print("viewModel.data after fetch : \(self.viewModel.data)")
        }
    }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
var c = ViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
c.changeViewModelStruct()
```

Console prints:

```
viewModel.data in didSet : 0
viewModel.data before fetch : 0
viewModel.data in fetchResponse : 10
viewModel.data after fetch : 10
```

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368) 
says like this:

> willSet and didSet observers are not called when a property is first initialized. They are only called when the property’s value is set outside of an initialization context.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I prefer using didSet observer than delegation or callback with fetchData function. So I use struct than class. If there is no way to use struct with async mutating function, I should use class.