# Repository pattern in Swift: value or reference type?

Tags: swift, repository-pattern

**EDIT**:
I've decided to rephrase my question to make it general as was intended and to not put too much emphasis on a code, you can find the old one below. (similar question about VMs - [Swift: Should ViewModel be a struct or class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913904/swift-should-viewmodel-be-a-struct-or-class))

In general/by default if you would like to add a repository pattern to your project would you implement repositories as classes or structs? And why? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

As an examples

"I would use classes

- easier to handle resources (e.g. db connection, etc.)
- no need to make methods mutating if they are changing internal state of a repo
- I like to use dictionary/hashmap as a simple caching mechanism
- etc
  "

or "I would use structs

- less interference between instances of a repo, easier to reason about
- etc
  "

As you can see personally I'm leaning more towards classes but once was told that structs are better here. So I'm trying to build sort of a mental model here.

**OLD**:
I'd like to gather pros and cons of making repositories a value or a reference types.
For example having

```
protocol UserRepository {
    func get(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<User, MyError>
}
```

should we make implementation a class

```
class LocalUserRepository {
    func get(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<User, MyError> {
        ...
    }
}
```

or a struct

```
struct LocalUserRepository {
    func get(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<User, MyError> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make class.

Answer (score 0):

No. Use a caseless enumeration. Other types are only necessary if you have instance members.

Also, use a subscript. Methods are only useful if they have meaningful names.

```swift
protocol UserRepository {
  static subscript(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<User, MyError> { get }
}

enum LocalUserRepository: UserRepository {
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, examples are just an examples, for sure you’d need things inside (e.g. datasources or something)

Comment: Add a thing then!